# Limiting search result for Anonymous users

Tags: search-results

We are having a SharePoint 2013 Web application with windows based authentication. It has an extended web application with anonymous access enabled. The anonymous site is available to public. As of now, when the anonymous user searches the site, it shows result with all the Lists and Document Library which Anonymous user does not have access. When they click on this it ask for user name and password.

How can we restrict the search result for anonymous user to return only public content and not the List and document Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each site collection where you have Anonymous Access enabled, make sure that you only permit "Lists and libraries" and not the "Entire Web site" option.

> ## Anonymous Access
>
> Specify what parts of your Web site (if any) anonymous users can access. **If you select Entire Web site, anonymous users will be able to view all pages in your Web site and view all lists and items which inherit permissions from the Web site**. If you select Lists and libraries, anonymous users will be able to view and change items only for those lists and libraries that have enabled permissions for anonymous users.

[image]

This also effect search, since search mirror permission level set on each item. No access = no search result.